# App does not exist at path error while running the calabash-ios test even though app exists in the right path

Tags: calabash-ios

x-code : 8.0

App does not exist at path or is not an app bundle.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-2.2.2/lib/run_loop/device_agent/app/DeviceAgent-Runner.app

Bundle must:

1. be a directory that exists,
2. have a .app extension,
3. contain an Info.plist,
4. and the app binary (CFBundleExecutable) must exist
   (ArgumentError)
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-2.2.2/lib/run_loop/app.rb:19:in `initialize'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-2.2.2/lib/run_loop/device_agent/ios_device_manager.rb:86:in`new'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-2.2.2/lib/run_loop/device_agent/ios_device_manager.rb:86:in `launch'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-2.2.2/lib/run_loop/device_agent/client.rb:1233:in`launch_cbx_runner'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-2.2.2/lib/run_loop/device_agent/client.rb:264:in `launch'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-2.2.2/lib/run_loop/device_agent/client.rb:140:in`run'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/run_loop-2.2.2/lib/run_loop.rb:113:in `run'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.20.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:408:in`block in new_run_loop'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.20.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:406:in `times'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.20.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:406:in`new_run_loop'
   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.20.3/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:365:in `relaunch'
   /Users/sbg1/Documents/SBGcode/GitCucumber_trunk/sbg-mobile-test/banking/PBBI/features/ios/support/01_launch.rb:28:in`Before'

Comment: Update latest version of ruby. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Calabash iOS no longer supports Apple's system ruby.

We recommend you install ruby 2.3.1 with rbenv.  We recommend you avoid rvm.

Please see this wiki page for details.

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Ruby-on-MacOS

Answer (score 0):

Verify that `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/run_loop-4.1.0/lib/run_loop/device_agent/app/DeviceAgent-Runner.app` exists.

For me, only `DeviceAgent-Runner.app.zip` was in the `app` directory and once I unzipped it to `DeviceAgent-Runner.app` Calabash iOS worked.